# Changing JQuery UI slider display attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I create a Jquery UI slider like this:

```
$(this.slider).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        max: st,
        min: 0,
        step: 1,
        value: st,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            vp.loadImage((st) - ui.value);
        }
    });
```

How can I then control it's display attribute? I have tried the following:

```
$(this.slider).slider.attr('display','none');
$(this.slider).slider().attr('display', 'none');
```

Comment: `$("#slider-vertical").hide();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working like this:

```
$(this.slider).hide();
```